convex combination of probability measures
$\left( \Omega,\mathcal{A} \right)$ is a measurable space and $\mu,\nu$  are probability measures on it.
Prove any convex combination of $\mu$ and $\nu$ is also a probability measure on this space. Specifically, for $\lambda_1, \lambda _2 \ge 0$ with $\lambda_1 +\lambda_2 =1$, defined by, $\left(\lambda_1 \mu + \lambda_2 \nu  \right)\left( A \right)= \lambda_1 \mu\left( A \right)+\lambda_2 \nu\left( A \right) .~A\in \mathcal{A}$.
It must be shown: $\mu\left( \Omega \right) =1$ and $\mu\left( A \right) \in \left[ 0,1 \right]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$
Intuitively it also makes sense, but I can't come to a real conclusion, so that I can use, ($\lambda_1 , \lambda _2 \ge 0$ with $\lambda_1 +\lambda_2 =1$), for example.

Let's start with the simplest: it must be shown that
$$
(\lambda_1 \mu + \lambda_2 \nu)(\Omega)=1,.
$$
This should be quite obvious. If not let us know.

Suppose $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are two probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, then to show that $\mu$, defined via $\mu(A)=\lambda_1\nu(A)+\lambda_2\nu_2(A)$, is also a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, all that you need to show is that $\mu$ is a measure and that $\mu(\Omega)=1$.
To show that $\mu$ is a measure, it is trivially nonnegative and $\mu(\varnothing)=\lambda_1\nu_1(\varnothing)+\lambda_2\nu_2(\varnothing)=0$. And for any countably disjoint sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\right)=\lambda_1\nu_1\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\right)+\lambda_2\nu_2\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda_1\nu_1(A_n)+\lambda_2\nu_2(A_n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n).
$$
Lastly, $\mu(\Omega)=\lambda_1\nu_1(\Omega)+\lambda_2\nu_2(\Omega)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$.
This completes the argument with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq 0$ and $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$.

thank you very much, I have understood everything :)

No problem, consider accepting the answer so that the question can be closed! In any case, I am happy to help and please let me know if there are any other questions.
